# Custom render.continuous in table1::table1()

Tags: r

## Problem Statement

I would like to summarize ordinal variables in terms of both central tendency (i.e., mean, median) and the frequency breakdown of observations within each category using the `table1()` function from the `table1` package.

I have written the function `render.ordinal()` below to try to achieve this. However, this seems to lead to strange behavior in the table, such as misplacement of numbers and recycling.

## Custom `render.continuous` Function

```
# custom rendering function
render.ordinal <- function(x, value.prefix = "= ") {
  
  require(scales)
  
  N <- sum(!is.na(x))
  nmiss <- sum(is.na(x))
  mean <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  median <- median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  freqs <- table(factor(x))
  pcts <- freqs / N
  freqs_formatted <- paste0(freqs, " (", percent(as.numeric(pcts)), ")")
  names(freqs_formatted) <- paste0(value.prefix, names(freqs), ", n (%)")
  
  out <- c("",
           "N" = N,
           "Mean / Median" = paste0(sprintf("%.2f", mean), " / ", sprintf("%.2f", median)),
           freqs_formatted)
  
  out
  
}
```

## Reproducible Example

I'll demonstrate the issue by comparing the distributions of the number of gears, number of carbeurators, and number of cylinders in automatic (`am == 1`) vs. standard (`am == 0`) cars in the `mtcars` dataset.

You can see that, for example, the results using `table1(..., render.continuous = render.ordinal)` do not match those from `table()`. There is some vector length discrepancy causing the issue.

```
# cross-tabulation of transmission type by number of carbs.
with(mtcars, {table(carb, ifelse(am == 1, "Auto.", "Std."))})
carb Auto. Std.
   1     4    3
   2     4    6
   3     0    3
   4     3    7
   6     1    0
   8     1    0

# call table1() with custom render.continuous
library(table1)
table1(~ gear + carb + cyl | ifelse(am == 1, "Auto.", "Std."), 
       data = mtcars, 
       render.continuous = render.ordinal)
```

This yields the following warning.

```
Warning messages:
1: In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
2: In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

And the output, with incorrect placement of numbers.
[image: table1() output with custom render.continuous]

## Question

How can I revise `render.ordinal()` to get around this issue? I would prefer to not create separate numeric and factor versions of every ordinal variable and enter them into `table1()` separately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by the developer after I posted the issue [here](https://github.com/benjaminrich/table1/issues/59#issuecomment-877253506).